# Blank page output when using Entry Status in nested Switchee statement

Tags: ee2, templates, switchee

I am trying to use a nested Switchee statement to display an embedded template but the results are a blank page. Using default status group and EE 2.11.5. I feel like I am missing something basic here.

*The logic is:* If SEGMENT 2 is NOT BLANK then display correct embedded template based on the Entry Status.

PASS (shows _sometemplate_home): xyz.com/somegroup
FAIL (shows blank): xyz.com/somegroup/open-status-entry
FAIL (shows blank): xyz.com/somegroup/closed-status-entry

```
<!-- COMPLETE somegroup/index.html template -->

{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}

{case value="''"}
    {embed="somegroup/_sometemplate-home"}
{/case}

{case value="#^P(\d+)$#"}
    {embed="somegroup/_sometemplate-home"}
{/case}

{case default="Yes"}
    {switchee variable="{status}" parse="inward"}

        {case value="open"}
            {embed="somegroup/_sometemplate-open"}
        {/case}

        {case value="closed"}
            {embed="somegroup/_sometemplate-closed"}
        {/case}

    {/switchee}
{/case}   
{/exp:switchee}
```

Comment: I am starting to think the issue is because at this stage no channel entries have been parsed so there is no Status field to check for...

Comment: As answered below by Jelle, there was no channel entries yet so nothing to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @checyney said there is no channel:entries loop yet. I'd suggest you do it something like this:

```
{case default="Yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries}
        {switchee variable="{status}" parse="inward"}

            {case value="open"}
                {embed="somegroup/_sometemplate-open" the_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            {/case}

            {case value="closed"}
                {embed="somegroup/_sometemplate-closed" the_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            {/case}

        {/switchee}
    {/exp:channel:entries}    

{/case}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I can't believe I didn't see that until I had asked the question.